# Passing a parameter from control to custom Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I am creating a class that derive from `AuthorizeAttribute` class. I need to pass the parameter in my controller, where I decorate the derive class. How can I achieve that in this situation?

```
[SampleAuthorization]
public ActionResult GetFileContent(Guid planId)
{
}

 public class PlanAuthorizationAttribute :  AuthorizeAttribute
 {
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // how can I use my planId to my custom plan authorizaton        

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the values in `authorizationContext.RequestContext.HttpContext` or if `planId` is part of the route you can even find it in `authorizationContext.RequestContext.RouteData`.

Comment: Then its probably only in the `.HttpContext.Params` because its not part of the route data.

Comment: yap they are there but how can I access that?

Comment: You get the `AuthorizationContext` passed to `OnAuthorization` as a parameter!